# Show that the sequence is increasing and unbounded

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-calculus

I am unable to proceed after a certain point in a small proof, which I present below. I can understand why the sequence under question is increasing and would like to further understand why it is unbounded. I additionally include necessary definitions and results used in the proof at the end of the post.

> Let $g: [a, \infty) \rightarrow $ be right-continous with finite left limits and of finite variation on $[a, \infty)$.
>
> Define $T_0 := a$ and let $T_1$ be the minimum of $a+1$ and the first time when $V_{[a,t]}(g)$ exceeds $\frac{1}{2}$, i.e.
>
> $$
> T_1 : = \min \left\{ a+1, \inf \left\{ t \in (a, \infty):V_{[a,t]}(g) > \frac{1}{2} \right\} \right\},
> $$
>
> with the covention that $\inf \emptyset = \infty$. Since $t \mapsto V_{[a,t]}(f)$ is right-continous, we have $T_1 >a.$  Further, define $T_2, T_3, \ldots $ inducively by
>
> $$
> T_{k+1} : = \min \left\{ a+k+1, \inf \left\{ t \in (T_k, \infty): V_{[T_k,t]}(g) > \frac{1}{2} \right\} \right\}.
> $$
>
> Then $T_{k+1} > T_{k}$, and since each $g$ is of finite variation we have $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} T_k = +\infty.$

I understand how it is concluded that $T_{k+1} > T_k$. To elaborate, first observe $V_{[a,t]}(g)$ is right-continuous and is equal to $0$ for $t = a$. Thus, by right-continuity, there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all $t \in [a, a+\delta)$

$$
V_{[a,t]}(g) < \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Therefore, $\inf \left\{ t \in (a, \infty): V_{[a,t]}(g) > \frac{1}{2} \right\} > a$, and

$$
T_1 : = \min \left\{ a+1, \inf \left\{ t \in (a, \infty): V_{[a,t]}(g) > \frac{1}{2} \right\} \right\} > a = T_0.
$$

Thus, $a = T_0 < T_1 \leq a+1$.

With similar reasoning, we have

$$
T_2 : = \min \left\{ \underbrace{a+2}_{> T_1}, \underbrace{ \inf \left\{ t \in (T_1, \infty): V_{[T_1,t]}(g) > \frac{1}{2} \right\} }_{> T_1} \right\} > T_1.
$$

Thus, $a = T_0 < T_1 < T_2 \leq a+2$.

Eventually, we can conclude that

$$
T_k < T_{k+1} \leq a + k + 1.
$$

However, I don't understand why the last statement is true:

> since each $g$ is of finite variation we have $\lim_{k \rightarrow
> > \infty} T_k = +\infty.$

Maybe someone could make this clear. Relevant definitions follow below.

---

- Let $I$ be a real interval and $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. The *total variation* of $f$ over $[a,b] \subset I$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
V_{[a,b]}(f) := \sup_{ \substack{ a = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n = b \\ n \in \mathbb{N}} } \sum_{i=1}^{n} |f(t_i) - f(t_{i-1})|
\end{equation}

(i.e. the supremum is taken taken over all possible partitions $a = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_n = b$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ).

- The function $f$ is said to be of finite variation on $I$ if $V_{[a,b]}(f) < \infty$ for all compact subintervals [a,b] of $I$.
- If $f$ is a right-continuous function on $I$, then for $c \in I$, $t \geq c$, the function $t \mapsto V_{[c,t]}(f)$ is also right-continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $T_{k+1}-T_k<1$ then $T_{k+1}<a+k+1,$ which implies $V_{[T_k,T_{k+1}]}\geq \tfrac12.$ Note $V_{[T_0,T_k]}=V_{[T_0,T_1]}(g)+\dots+V_{[T_{k-1},T_k]}(g).$ So either:

- $T_{k+1}\geq T_k+1,$ or
- $V_{[a,T_{k+1}]}(g)\geq V_{[a,T_{k}]}(g)+\tfrac 1 2.$

This means $T_k+2V_{[a,T_k]}(g)$ increases by at least $1$ as $k$ increases by $1$: if we define $S_k=T_k+2V_{[a,T_k]}(g)$ then $S_{k+1}\geq S_k+1.$ So $S_k\geq a+k$ for all $k.$ For any $T\geq a,$ if $k\geq T-a+2V_{[a,T]}$ then $T_k+2V_{[a,T_k]}(g)=S_k\geq T+2V_{[a,T]}(g),$ which forces $T_k\geq T.$ Hence $T_k$ is not strictly bounded by $T.$

Comment: Why do you need right-continuity for $V_{[T_0,T_k]}(g)=V_{[T_0,T_1]}(g)+\dots+V_{[T_{k-1},T_k]}(g)$? It holds for any $g$.  Could you add more details to the last two sentences?

Comment: @Holden: I have added some more explanation using an auxiliary definition "$S_k$"

Comment: What do you mean by the total variation of $g$? $g$ is defined on $[a, \infty)$ and is of finite variation on it, i.e. $g$ has finite variation on all compact subintervals of $[a,\infty)$. We would need to consider $\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} V_{[a,t]}(g)$ which might not be finite.

Comment: @Holden: Yeah, sorry. I was mixing up "finite variation" and "bounded variation"

Comment: Side question: if we define $\tilde{g}(s) := g(s)$ for all $s \notin \{ T_1, T_2, \ldots\}$ and $\tilde{g}(T_k) = \lim_{s \uparrow T_k}g(s)$, $k \in N$, do you see why it holds that $TV_{[T_k, T_{k+1}]}(\tilde{g}) \leq \frac{1}{2}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$?

Comment: @Holden: I don’t think that’s true. If $g(a+x)=100$ for $x\geq 1/10$ and zero otherwise, then $T_1$ will be $1/10$ and $\tilde g$ will have variation $100$ on $[T_1,T_2].$

Answer (score 2):

The sequence $(a + k)_{k \ge 0}$ is obviously unbounded, so we may ignore this part and assume that $(T_k)$ is inductively by $T_{k+1} = \inf \{t \in (T_k, \infty) \, | \, V_{[T_k, t]} > \frac12 \}$ - if we can show that the latter sequence is unbounded, then the minimum of the two unbounded sequences is also unbounded.

---

Suppose that $(T_k)$ were bounded above. Then, since the sequence is increasing, it would have a limit, $L$, say (which it approaches from below).

Now, since $g$ is of finite variation, $V_{[a,L]} \leq N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$. But then,

\begin{align}
V_{[a,T_{2N+1}]} &= V_{[a, T_1]} + V_{[T_1, T_2]} + ... + V_{[T_{2N}, T_{2N+1}]}\\
&\geq \frac12 + \frac12 + ... + \frac12\\
&= N + \frac12
\end{align}

But clearly $V_{[a, t]}$ is an increasing function (from the definition), so this implies that $T_{2N+1} > L$ which is a contradiction.

---

The general idea is that, $V_{[a,T_k]}$ is a sequence which tends to infinity, so if the $T_k$ had a limit, $L$, then the variation on $[a,L]$ would have to be infinite (it would be the sum of the variations on each $[T_k, T_{k+1}]$).

Comment: @Holden:  Although the Answer is posted to your Question, I'd be more cautious about making unilateral edits. Some of these are more substantive than correcting "typos" and would be better handled through Comments to the poster asking for clarifications.

Comment: @Holden I concur with "hardmath"; I have left the changes made by as they are not technically incorrect, but I do not partiularly understand why they were necessary - e.g. the change from equalities to inequalities (e.g. $V_{[a,L]} = N$ for some $N$,  changed to $V_{[a,L]} \le N$) - to me, the answer was clearer as before, though maybe I am missing something?...

Comment: @JohnDon I share the view that  making substantive changes requires further discussion. As for this case, it seems clear, that for the index of $T_{2N+1}$ to make sense, $N$ should be a natural number. The same is not true for $V_{[a,L]}(g)$ in general. I guess I should have made this clear.

Comment: @Holden Actually that's a good point; I think, in my original post I probably intended something along those lines, but forgot what I was doing! Thanks for the clarification!